Checking the definition of morphism of locally ringed spaces using adjunction between pushforward and inverse image sheaves
A morphism of locally ringed spaces $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\xrightarrow{}(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ consists of a continuous map $f:X\xrightarrow{}Y$ between the underlying topological spaces and a sheaf homomorphism $f^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_Y\xrightarrow{}f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ such that the induced ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\xrightarrow{}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)}\xrightarrow{}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for each $x\in X$ is local.
However, because the pushforward and the inverse image functor are adjoint to each other, a morphism $f^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_Y\xrightarrow{}f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ in $\mathit{Sh}(Y)$ is the same data as a morphism $f_\sharp: f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\xrightarrow{}\mathcal{O}_X$ in $\mathit{Sh}(X)$. For $x\in X$, the latter induces a map on stalks $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\xrightarrow{}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.
Is this map the same as the aforementioned $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\xrightarrow{}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)}\xrightarrow{}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$?
I feel that the answer should be yes. What I tried was using the uniqueness given by the universal property of colimits, without much success. If this is false, do we at least have that one is local if and only if the other one is local?
